# Why may I be getting empty data field from facebook?

Tags: facebook, api

Why may I be getting empty data field from facebook?

I saw [the](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17329454/facebook-graph-api-returning-empty-data-set) question, but the solution provided did not help me.

I have 5 friends on facebook and their count is correct, but the `data` is empty.

What may I try out?

Here is the query I am performing:

```
FB.API("me/friends", HttpMethod.GET, callback);
```

[image]

Comment: What query are you doing?

Comment: do ALL users have user_friends authorized?

Comment: @WizKid, I updated the question.

Comment: @luschn, what does it mean?